# dynamicSoql query

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

```
public class query
{

    public string accname{set;get;}
    public string accindustry{set;get;}
    public list<account>account{set;get;}

    public void result()
    {
        account=[select id,name,industry from account where name=:accname and industry=:accindustry];
    }

    public void dynamicsearch()
    {
        string dynquery='select id,name,industry from account';

        if((accname!=null&&accname!='')&&(accindustry!=null&&accindustry!=''))
        {
                dynquery=dynquery+'where name=\''+accname+'\'and industry=\''+accindustry+'\'';

        }
        else if(accname!=null&&accname!='')
        {
            dynquery=dynquery+'where name=\''+accname+'\'' ;
        }
        else if(accindustry!=null&&accindustry!='')
        {
            dynquery=dynquery+'where industry=\''+accindustry+'\'' ; 
        }

        account=database.query(dynquery);//error line
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  Can you please update with more details, otherwise this will get closed.  e.g. please include exact error messages and where the issue is.

Comment: Can you rename your class to something other than 'query'?  Not sure if that's the reason you're getting that error.

Comment: is it resolved?

Answer (score 1):

after account add space that may solve your issue, i guess

```
string dynquery='select id,name,industry from account '; //add space here
```

All other looks good to me.

### Updates -

```
string dynquery='select id,name,industry from account ';

if((accname!=null&&accname!='')&&(accindustry!=null&&accindustry!=''))
{
        dynquery=dynquery+' where name='+accname+'and industry='+accindustry;

}
else if(accname!=null&&accname!='')
{
    dynquery=dynquery+' where name='+accname ;
}
else if(accindustry!=null&&accindustry!='')
{
    dynquery=dynquery+' where industry='+accindustry ; 
}

account=database.query(dynquery);
```

An alternate way to write this:

```
// base query
string dynquery = 'SELECT id, name, industry FROM account';

// construct a list of criteria for where clause
List<String> whereClause = new List<String>();

// add accname if it exists
if( ! String.isBlank(accname))
{
    whereClause.add('name = :accname');
}

// add accindustry if it exists
if( ! String.isBlank(accindustry))
{
    whereClause.add('industry = :accindustry');
}

if(! whereClause.isEmpty())
{
    dynquery += ' WHERE ' + String.join(whereClause, ' AND ');
}

account = Database.query(dynquery);
```

Comment: no result same error will be comming

Comment: @RegalaguntaPraveen what is error first tell tht. Also try to debug the query in your code and check debug logs.

Comment: @RegalaguntaPraveen check my updates in my answer and try with that hope this solve your issue

Comment: @Ratan I guess still the space matters. First if clause, before `and` need a space

Comment: compaile the program run time error:Method does not exist or incorrect signature: database.query(String)

Comment: ofter modification also give the same error

Comment: @RegalaguntaPraveen instead of `database.query(dynquery)` try `system.database.query(dynquery)`

Comment: your modify the programing it is also give the same error:Method does not exist or incorrect signature: database.query(String)

Comment: @RegalaguntaPraveen tried with system.database.query() ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have conflicting classes (in addition to the other answers which will help after this is fixed).

Find your local class named `database` and change the name.

If you are unsure or say there is not class named database then try `system.database.query` and if that works then you have a class named database somewhere

I also confirmed that simply having a class named `query` will not cause this issue but will cause other potential issues and is just a bad idea. Given that you named a class `query` and from the error message it is likely that you do indeed have a class named database.

Answer (score 0):

```
Global class praveen implements Database.Batchable<Account> {

global Database.Querylocator start(DataBase.BatchableContext Bc) {
string Query='select name,discription from account';
return Database.getQuerylocator(Query);
}

global void execute(DataBase.BatchableContext Bc,list<Account>acc) {
for(Account a:acc){
a.discription=a.Account.discription;
acc.add(a);
}
update acc;
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext Bc){
}
}
//error:Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: Database.Querylocator at line 2 column 8
```